# Command button action using controller method

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller-extension

I have a command button where the action is a controller method. I am getting a visual force error `Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.`

I did some looking up and this requires AJAX. How would I get this to work?

Command Button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!resetPassword}" value="Reset Password" id="theButton" oncomplete="changePassword()"/>
```

Controller Method:

```
public String resetPassword() {
    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller method has a return type of `String`, but in order to be a valid target of a page action, the return type needs to be either `void` or `PageReference`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

```
public String test { get; set; }     
public PageReference resetPassword() {
            this.test = 'test';
            return null;
        }
```